# Iterating through two ArrayList with Nested While Statements - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, while-loop, iteration

I am trying to iterate through two ArrayLists (called sceneObjects and animationSceneObjects) and match the two based on a name field. Here is my code :

```
Iterator<AnimationObject> itr = animationObjects.iterator();
Iterator<SceneObject> itrMain = sceneObjects.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
            AnimationObject object = itr.next();
            //Remove the word node from the animation object name so it matches main object name.
            String  tmpString = object.animationobjectName.replace("node-", "");
            System.out.println("Animation Object name is" +tmpString);
            while (itrMain.hasNext()) {
                SceneObject objectMain = itrMain.next();
                System.out.println("Scene Object name is" +objectMain.objectName);
                if (tmpString.equals(objectMain.objectName)) {
                    System.out.println("Animation Object matched to main object array" +tmpString);
                    objectMain.animations = object.animationData;
                    objectMain.hasAnimations = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the code isn't working as intended - it only compares the first item in the itr iterator to the values of the itrMain iterator.

Can anyone spot what I have got wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reset `itrMain` before each run of the inner loop, otherwise - once you have exhausted the iterator the first time - the inner loop will never be invoked.

You can do it by re-assigning it with `sceneObjects.iterator()` before you reach the inner loop, or use an enhanced [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
Iterator<AnimationObject> itr = animationObjects.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Iterator<SceneObject> itrMain = sceneObjects.iterator();
       //    ^
       //   reassigning itrMain each iteration of the outer loop

            AnimationObject object = itr.next();
            //Remove the word node from the animation object name so it matches main object name.
            String  tmpString = object.animationobjectName.replace("node-", "");
            System.out.println("Animation Object name is" +tmpString);
            while (itrMain.hasNext()) {
                SceneObject objectMain = itrMain.next();
                System.out.println("Scene Object name is" +objectMain.objectName);
                if (tmpString.equals(objectMain.objectName)) {
                    System.out.println("Animation Object matched to main object array" +tmpString);
                    objectMain.animations = object.animationData;
                    objectMain.hasAnimations = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a new iterator for the inner loop ever time:

```
Iterator<AnimationObject> itr = animationObjects.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    AnimationObject object = itr.next();
    //Remove the word node from the animation object name so it matches main object name.
    String  tmpString = object.animationobjectName.replace("node-", "");
    System.out.println("Animation Object name is" +tmpString);

    Iterator<SceneObject> itrMain = sceneObjects.iterator();

    while (itrMain.hasNext()) {
        SceneObject objectMain = itrMain.next();
        System.out.println("Scene Object name is" +objectMain.objectName);
        if (tmpString.equals(objectMain.objectName)) {
            System.out.println("Animation Object matched to main object array" +tmpString);
            objectMain.animations = object.animationData;
            objectMain.hasAnimations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

or (perhaps more simply) use two `for` loops:

```
for (AnimationObject animation : animationObjects) {
    for (SceneObject scenes : sceneObjects) {
        // snip...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not restarting the inner iterator for every outer loop step. What you should really do is use the for-each loop.

```
for (AnimationObject ao : animationObjects) {
  ... your outer-loop code ...
  for (SceneObject so : sceneObjects) {
     ... your inner-loop code ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the itrMain iterator inside the first loop.
If you keep the same iterator, your first iteration will have consumed it.

```
Iterator<AnimationObject> itr = animationObjects.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Iterator<SceneObject> itrMain = sceneObjects.iterator();
    [...]
```